# PC doesn't detect phone's 5GHz hotspot bands

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, hotspot

I am using a redmi 9 phone, getting LTE mobile data and sharing it via hotspot to my PC.
And on the PC (win10) I'm using a T2U plus wi-fi adapter.

Using a 2.4GHz band hotspot it works fine, but when I switch it to 5GHz I suddenly can't detect it anymore... And my wi-fi adapter does seem to support 5GHz bands as I can detect my neighbors connections.

I don't really know what to do, tried various solutions like resetting settings, changing adapter to 5g only, changing SSID, updating drivers, etc...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 5 GHz Wi-Fi has a ton of channels. Not all adapters support all of them. Maybe ask a friend to use a Wi-Fi scanner app in their phone or laptop to check which channel is used.